# Concat all columns with pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to write a .txt file from a dataframe. I read that to do that I have to have a dataframe with a single column:
[image]

I'm trying to do that like this:

```
dataframe = dataframe.select(concat(*dataframe.columns).alias("Data"))
```

But it doesn't work, I think that the unpack of the columns gives some problems. And I don't want pass explicitly all the column names.
Someone has an idea? Thank you

This is the output after updating code thanks to @Jonathan Lam

```
dataframe.show(truncate = False)
print(*[col(column) for column in dataframe.columns])
dataframe = dataframe.select(concat(*[col(column) for column in dataframe.columns]).alias("Data"))
dataframe.show(truncate = False)
```

[image]

Finally I found the problem: when concat meets a 'null' value the whole value becomes null. So I have to find a way to change that

Comment: you don't need to have a single column to write a df as txt. can you share how you want the output to look like, and why you need a single column? re: concat, it should work just fine -- what errors/issues are you facing? you could also look into `concat_ws()`

Comment: I have to have a single column, look the log error when I call `write().text()`

Comment: use `concat_ws('', *dataframe.column)` instead of the `concat`. you can provide a delimiter as the first input (instead of `''`) and it also takes care of null fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach should be correct, just test:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1", "2", "3")],
    schema=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
)

df.show(3, False)
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |
+----+----+----+
```

But I am using the pyspark api `col`:

```
df.select(
    func.concat(*[func.col(col) for col in df.columns]).alias('concat')
).show(10, False)
+------+
|concat|
+------+
|123   |
+------+
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work, that's my code:
````print(*[col(column) for column in dataframe.columns])
        dataframe = dataframe.select(concat(*[col(column) for column in dataframe.columns]).alias("Data"))
        dataframe.show(truncate = False)````